# Try to open twice a document, only on server, with office documents

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got an issue with my aspx page, that open one document.

The problem is when I click on open, of the dialog box open, it will open the document, and the same document a second time in read only.

And this happened only when i run my silverlight application on a server, not localhost.

THe code calling the aspx(silverlight page behind code) :

```
ub = (new Uri(HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri, "ViewDocument.aspx?&connexion=" + connexion + ";&id=" + id.ToString()));


if (HtmlPage.IsPopupWindowAllowed)
{
    HtmlPopupWindowOptions opt = new HtmlPopupWindowOptions();
    HtmlPage.PopupWindow(ub, "file", opt);
}
else
{
    HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(ub);
}

HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(ub);
```

And the aspx page :

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(vChaineConnexion);
conn.Open();
string v_requete = "";

if (id != null)
{
    v_requete = "SELECT doc, extension " +
                 "FROM t_doc " +
                 "WHERE id= "+ id.ToString();
}

//si la requête n'est pas vide
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(v_requete))
{

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(v_requete, conn);
    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
    OracleCommandBuilder ocb = new OracleCommandBuilder(da);
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

    if (id != null)
    {
        da.Fill(dataset, "Extension");
    }


    //retrieving binary data of pdf from dataset to byte array
    byte[] blob = (byte[])dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0];
    string extension = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();

    if(extension.equals(".doc"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
    }

    if (id != null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "Attachment; filename=" + id.ToString() + extension);
    }
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length", blob.Length.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(blob);
    if (HttpContext.Current.Response.IsClientConnected)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); //instead of Response.End()
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

I don't understand, why it tried to open the document two times, only on servers, while it works fine on localhost.

I go through my method, calling the aspx only one time, and at the moment I click open on the popupWindow, it open twice the document.

And it seems, this happened with word, but not with a pdf..

Correction : all office documents... (office 2010 on my desk)

See a error message quickly : `online services smartscreen unavailable`

I think this is the probleme but I don't understant why.

Why?

Comment: Same version of Word on both client and server?

Comment: It use the office app on the client desk, because it is open with the popup window on the client desk. Sorry, I misexplaind it. I meant that it was not working well, while not on localhost. I think it changes the situation...

Comment: I know you meant on the client desk. I was wondering if it was the same version of Word in the case where it works, as in the case where it fails.

Comment: Sorry, I though I don't explained it well. Well, I open the document on my desk in server, and localhost run. So, yes. It's not really a fail strictly, because it open a first document well, but try to open the same in the same second.

Comment: Add an edit, with an error message I saw quickly.